# Two simple questions about STI implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sti

I am using STI for my user models. I have an User class, and the subclasses Seller and Customer. A user cannot be both, so I think STI is alright for this case.
I have two questions:

1. How do I restrict the creation of User instances, so only sellers or customers can be created? I guess I could validate the presence of Type, but that doesnt feel very right to me.
2. Can I have extra, different fields for sellers and customers with STI? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only allow saving of users and customers by doing:

```
validates_inclusion_of :type, :in => [:customer, :user]
```

As far as your second question, the answer is: add columns.   If you add columns for the customer the user model will ignore them, so no big deal.  It depends on your use case though, in some cases it's best to avoid STI.

Comment: would you try `add_column :child_name, :field_name, :type_name`? That doesn't seem to work for me.